# Why did the U.S. government lower the funding of the IRS?

Tags: united-states, government, taxes

> Also needed: better tax enforcement through restored and increased
> funding of the IRS. **An expert review of data released by the
> Congressional Budget Office and the Treasury Department indicates that
> every $1 of additional investment in the IRS would yield $11 in
> increased tax collections and between 2020 and 2029 would raise $1.1
> trillion in additional revenue over and above current projections.**

https://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/082415/whats-wrong-american-tax-system.asp

Why did the U.S. government lower the funding of the IRS? Did they have a good reason to do so? According to the above, funding the IRS is a good investment for the U.S. government allowing it to generate more revenues, so why did the U.S. government didn't maintain the funding or even increase it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There has been a steady decline in enforcement of tax laws against the wealthiest individuals since the Reagan administration. The people who stand to lose if the tax laws are adequately enforced have bought themselves some democracy and managed to get legislators (mostly Republicans) to cut enforcement funding from the IRS and to also legislate rules that hamstring what enforcement there is.

Comment: which is particularly stupid, if you look at it from the perspective of whats good for the country. IRS has a 5:1 ROI, even 10:1 from some reports https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p4450.pdf

Comment: “For the good of the country”? This is the US, the land of unenlightened self-interest.

Comment: I downvoted this because although I don't think it's wrong per se, such a bold claim requires extensive sources.

Comment: @user253751 the user below has given citation, maybe you can look that up

Comment: [Biden proposes to reverse that.](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/04/27/business/economy/biden-american-families-plan.html)

Comment: Could be a good answer if you provide a quote for every one of your statements.

Comment: As it stands, this answer is unsubstantiated rumor.

Comment: @AdilMohammed doesn't matter what the other answer has, **this** answer has no sources

Comment: @user253751 you are right

Comment: @user253751 "A recent report from the Treasury Department's inspector general concluded that at the IRS, 'high-income taxpayers are generally not a collection priority, nor is there a strategy in place to address nonpayment by high-income taxpayers.' As evidence, the report showed that the agency failed to recover more than 60 percent of the $4 billion in back taxes owed by those making more than $1.5 million." - [Newsweek 03/2021](https://www.newsweek.com/government-just-admitted-it-doesnt-really-try-collect-rich-peoples-taxes-1577610). I agree this answer needs sources, just wanted to note.

Comment: [Please add some references.](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/should-we-have-a-back-it-up-rule-for-answers)

Answer (score 38):

This is not caused by the US government in general, this is caused by the Republicans who have been in control of the House for most of the past three decade.

Republicans are ideologically opposed to a strong government and want to minimize taxes in general. Thus for ideological reasons they tend to view the IRS as an enemy: it's the agency in charge of collecting taxes and fund the government.

From [a detailed article by Eric Levitz](https://nymag.com/intelligencer/article/republican-war-irs-threatens-infrastructure-deal.html):

> The right’s fixation on IRS malfeasance reflects its opposition to the agency’s core mission. For the bulk of its existence, the conservative movement’s leadership has disdained income taxation in general, and progressive taxation in particular. This antipathy is implicit in the modern GOP’s unwavering commitment to lowering federal taxes on the wealthy, irrespective of the nation’s contemporary tax rates, budget deficit, or national spending.

In the past decade Republicans have been quite successful at decreasing the IRS budget, and especially defunding its enforcement division:

> Upon taking the House in 2011, Republicans set about slashing the IRS’s budget, which fell from $14 billion that year to $11.5 billion in 2020. As a result, the agency’s number of staffers declined by 22 percent, while its enforcement division cut its payroll by 30 percent — even as the number of individual tax returns in the U.S. grew by more than 7 percent
>
> Between 2010 and 2018, the audit rate on returns with more than $1 million in income dropped by 63 percent. In the former year, nearly all corporations worth over $20 billion were subject to audits; in the latter year, only half were. White-collar crime went rampant. The tax gap — the difference between what Americans owe to the federal government and what they pay — swelled to an estimated $441 billion in 2013, and $584 billion in 2019. The current IRS commissioner, Chuck Rettig, believes that these were underestimates, and that the current tax gap is closer to $1 trillion.

Mathematically this strategy causes the government income to decrease, thus increasing the deficit:

> It’s worth noting that no great scandal initiated the GOP’s defunding of the tax police. Rather, House Republicans pursued downsizing the IRS as an end in itself. They saw that their budget cuts were increasing the deficit by reducing tax collections, and then pushed for yet more budget cuts anyway.

Republicans also claim that the IRS is corrupt and/or politically biased against them. The [same article](https://nymag.com/intelligencer/article/republican-war-irs-threatens-infrastructure-deal.html) debunks these claims.

Comment: "Thus for ideological reasons they tend to view the IRS as an enemy:" - I'd argue it's less "ideological" and far more "pragmatic" - or cynically self-interested, imo.

Comment: @Dai I'd argue it's both. Ideologically they support the proposition that government doesn't work; this policy helps ensure it doesn't.

Comment: "Republicans are ideologically opposed to a strong government." That's not entirely true. They are opposed to government control over aspects of life they don't want to be controlled.

Comment: @Dai For Republican legislators, yes. For a large portion of the Republican voter block, rural voters in the southern and central states who are statistically some of the poorest in the country and most reliant on welfare, it's entirely ideological - they benefit in no way from (and are in fact harmed by) reduced tax enforcement on people with >$1 million income per year or large corporations. It's just that the ideology has been entirely constructed for them and fed to them by the people that *do* benefit.

Comment: Republicans have socially conservative and small government wings, sometimes in conflict.

Comment: @qwr Then why do politicians from those wings only ever argue with The Left and never with each other? It's almost like they tacitly approve of each others' beliefs. I'm not sure which one so I can't link to it, but one of the Alt-Right Playbook videos describes this effect.

Comment: The decrease in inflation-adjusted dollars is a [longterm trend](https://www.taxpolicycenter.org/sites/default/files/styles/original_optimized/public/book_images/2.8.2_fig2_0.png?itok=53PdhIOG)... some of the better increases look to be during the full trinary Republican control in the mid 2000s.  Republicans dispute with each other about as much as Democrats do... both of which are pretty disgustingly rare... a common consequence of the nuclear partisan world we now live in, which (since we're just going to opinions now in "comments" apparently?)... both sides are responsible for.

Comment: @qwr thats the problem of a two party system. Just dividing the political spectrum into merely "left and right" is completely wrong to begin with, splitting it into a mere A or B choice is completely bonkery in any context expect when you want to become a pretend-democracy

Answer (score 9):

The IRS is one of the government agencies that regularily steps on the **wrong** toes - those of people who have money, influence and connections. At the same time it doesn't have any active programs that directly benefit any of those people, because it doesn't do the spending side.

As a result, it has few people who speak or lobby in its favour and many who actively work against it. On the abstract, most people agree that the IRS is doing a necessary and beneficial job - but when it comes to the specific actions, especially those that affect us, we aren't exactly fans.

And while spending on the IRS would have a positive ROI, the same is true for the other side, especially considering the very rich: Spending to **avoid** paying taxes, be it on tax advisors, corporate lawyers to structure your company or investments in a way that avoids taxes, or lobbying against new taxes, for the reduction of old taxes, *or the reduction of enforcement* **also** has a positive ROI.

This is not limited to the IRS, but a global phenomenon. When the Cum-Ex scandal became public, damage control went into overdrive, and as a result many of the penalties stand uncollected to this day. In my country, a unit of our IRS equivalent that uncovered massive tax fraud among the rich was disbanded instead of promoted. And so on.

tl;dr: Nobody particularily **likes** the IRS. Most people consider it a necessary evil. Thus it has few advocates and many enemies, especially among those who pay a lot of taxes. But people who pay a lot of taxes also have ways to influence legislation.

Comment: What are your sources for these claims?

Comment: @qwr any of the other answers sources combined with the Republican donor list

Answer (score -4):

Few people in the electorate — basically only those who don't pay taxes because they don't have work because they don't have an education — don't have a negative sentiment towards the IRS. These are the same people who don't vote, so nobody cares. OK; some of those who don't work are on the way of being educated: the students who supported Sanders.

All others are silently happy that they are never audited. Therefore it's easy to silently let the IRS die from attrition: Not many people besides the students and their teachers object, and a few Democrats, until their main donors sit them down for a talk.

The argument brought forward by conservatives who feel they must answer to the students is that the IRS is the executive arm of a tax system that is too complicated and too invasive, and nobody wants that. Funding it so that it can enforce an obsolete and byzantine code would be funding the wrong policy, as a WSJ article recently suggested, calling to ["defund" the IRS](https://www.wsj.com/articles/defund-joe-bidens-irs-11625520412).

Comment: You'd think educated people would be able to differentiate between the entity that creates overly-complex tax law and sets taxation rates (Congress) and the entity that ensures that the taxes are collected according to the law (the IRS).

Comment: @RussellBorogove I have trouble even understanding that sentence so, no.

Comment: The IRS doesn't make the rules. Defunding the IRS only makes things better for cheaters -- that is, for people who are actively trying to hurt America for their own benefit.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Ah. As I said, everybody tries to pay as few taxes as possible, nobody likes to be audited, so nobody likes the IRS. That is independent of any rules.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica and yet without it, the country would collapse (as it is already doing, but more quickly). Educated people - even temporarily unemployed ones - don't want their country to collapse.

Comment: @user253751 Isn't it funny how we are able to smooth over contradictions between our values and our behavior. As an aside, many libertarian right-wing conservatives would not underwrite that a substantially smaller budget would doom the U.S., to the contrary: A deep federal state dooms the country. *De-funding it is a good thing.* Withholding taxes is doing a service to the country. That's another funny thing: that we tend to nurse theories that benefit ourselves.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica the budget is not the IRS. Continuing the current budget while deleting the IRS will plunge the economy into hyperinflation and China will be the new world superpower. Meanwhile, changing the budget while continuing to fund the IRS will give them what they want.

Comment: @user253751 Errrr... thinking that funding the IRS will prevent China from becoming the new world superpower is bordering on the delusional ;-).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I didn't say it would prevent it. But rather, that not doing so will guarantee it.

Comment: @user253751 That's why we should first delete the CCP, and then the IRS. Everybody wins.